# how can add header parameters to rest API in wso2 apim 2.6.0 via In Flow mediator

Tags: header, wso2-api-manager, wso2, mediator

I have Rest API on wso2 apim 2.6.0 that has json input and output.And has Get resource. I  want to add header parameters to it. so I need In flow mediator.

I use this mediator but it does not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="newUser" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <header name="caller-token" scope="transport" value="234"/>
    <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
    <header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Bearer dd"/>
    <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="transport" value="https://onlineapi.agah.com/api/v1/"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <log level="full"/>
</sequence>
```

after invoking it in store I get this Error:
(400) Error: Not Found
Response headers:
content-type: application/octet-stream

Comment: does that work with curl or any other REST client like Postman?

Comment: It works with Postman. and I have 4 header parameter there. so I need to add them in some way into my API definition. but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a CORS issue. You need to enabled custom headers in the CORS rules. Add your custom headers to the `CORS` section in `api-manager.xml`. This affects to all APIs. If you want to add this for a particular API only, you can configure it in the API itself.

Rer: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Enabling+CORS+for+APIs

Comment: I use this but I get error: "The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported." . I think this solution can not be my solution because for example I have 'authorization' header and wso2 has this header too with different value.so I can't call API with two 'authorization' header with different values.In CORS I have define my required header but the uses who call API fill it,but I want my required headers filled in API definition

Comment: Is there any reason you want to enable `<Access-Control-Allow-Credentials>`? And see this for how to set a different header for GW authentication. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Securing+APIs

Comment: I fix the problem with first mediator I mentioned in my question. The problem was about the url I gave for production endpoint not about the adding required headers to API definition. So we can use that mediator with header tags for adding desired headers.